# Mysql - Order by specific data within a field

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I'm working with an external CSV product feed that is imported into a database, the results of each row are displayed to the end-user in a comparison table.

A particular column holds numerous details that I wish to sort by independently. The feed/table structure cannot be changed.

Example of the db feed table:

```
MODEL    | SPECIFICATIONS                                            | AGE
Car 1A   | 1000 miles recorded, 10 previous owners, No tax included  | 3 years
Car 1B   | 1000 miles recorded, 5 previous owners, No tax included   | 5 years
Car 1C   | 6000 miles recorded, 7 previous owners, No tax included   | 5 years
Bike 1D  | 3000 miles recorded, 5 previous owners, 100 tax included  | 4 years
```

Currently my mysql_query uses an 'ORDER BY model' statement.

I'd like to display the comparison table sorted by the number of 'previous owners' within the SPECIFICATIONS column.

Is there a way to do this within an ORDER BY statement?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your table setup in a dummy `MySQL` database and came up with the following solution.

```
SELECT *, CAST(TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(specifications, ',', -2), ' ', 2)) as unsigned integer) as previousowners  
FROM dbfeed    
ORDER BY previousowners;
```

It assumes that the specifications field has at least two sections separated by , and that there is a space between the number of owners and the text "previous owners".

Comment: This works very well for what I wanted, thanks. Due to the data structure I could quite safely remove the '2' SUBSTRING_INDEX , leaving the TRIM and -2 SUBSTR in place to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it's rather complicated and fragile - hence the [first rule of database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

Something like....

```
ORDER BY CAST (
    SUBSTR(specifications
    , LOCATE(', ', specifications)
    , LOCATE(' ', specifications, LOCATE(', ', specifications)+2)
    )
) AS INT;
```

Will find the string between ', ' and a subsequent ' '.

But you'll get unusual results if the format is not exactly as per your examples.

Comment: The third parameter to MySQL `SUBSTR` is the _length_ not the _end index_ so you either need to calculate this or use `2` and assume there will be < 99 previous owners and that there will be a trailing space for single digit cases.

Comment: @mikej: Yes indeed, well spotted. But it is possible to get the length between ', ' and ' ' ... ORDER BY CAST (
    SUBSTR(specifications
    , LOCATE(', ', specifications)
    , LOCATE(' ', specifications, LOCATE(', ', specifications)+2) - LOCATE(', ', specifications)
    )
) AS INT;